# Preventing a form submit works... too well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that I don't want to be submitted the first time submit is clicked, but the second time it should work like a normal submit. So I added a `not-submittable` class to the form on load, then after the first click remove that class... which should (I think) make it submit normally. But, this doesn't happen. The first click works as expected, removes the class and changes the button text. The second click, however, does the exact same thing. So, what am I missing here?

jQuery:

```
  $('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').addClass('not-submittable');

  $('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE.not-submittable').click(function(event) {
      $('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').removeClass('not-submittable');
      $('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').val('Continue');
      $('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').removeAttr('disabled');
    return false;
  });
```

Pre-javascript button:

```
<input type="submit" class="Button" value="Submit Survey" id="ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE" name="ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE">
```

Comment: You'll need to test for the existence of the class and act accordingly.

Comment: Look into jQuery [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead.  You can use it to do something **one** time.

Comment: NITPICK Do not keep doing $(...) over and over again. Use chaining or store it into a variable. Doing the same look up over and over again is SLOW.

Comment: @Jay, isn't the class tested for in the `.click` function since I specified `#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE.not-submittable`?
@Sparky, I can't use `.one` due to how the rest of the code works. @epascarello, I do chain where I can, this is just stripped down code I'm using for figuring out this problem. The above is actually dozens of lines apart.

Comment: Makes no sense... then show more code.  Just use `one()` to block submit using a `preventdefault()`; any other code should still work.

Comment: The form cannot be submitted until certain conditions are met. These conditions could be met on the first or 20th submit. Using `.one` won't work in this case. I didn't post the rest of the code because it's almost 200 lines and mostly irrelevant to the problem I'm having.

Comment: However, still a failure to explain why the most logical & simple solution is no good.

Comment: @Samsquanch I updated to account for that new information

Comment: OP's comment:  _"These conditions could be met on the first or 20th submit."_  ~ **Perhaps you should rephrase the first sentence of your question then:**  _"I have a form that I don't want to be submitted the first time submit is clicked, but the second time it should work like a normal submit."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

         $('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').click(function (event) {
             if (!$('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').hasClass(".not-submittable")) {

                 //do all conditions you wish on first click

                 //if condidition meets add this class to button
                 $('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').addClass(".not-submittable");

                 //stop form submit
                 event.preventDefault();
             }
             else {

                 //calls when button have .not-submittable class may be second or any no of clicks
                 $('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').removeClass('not-submittable');
                 $('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').val('Continue');
                 $('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').removeAttr('disabled');
                 //commented return false so form submits normally
             }
         });

     });
```

Comment: I ended up going with something similar to this. Although I realize the wording of my original question was not ideal, this was the only thing that ended up working as expected. Specifically I used: `if(!$(this).hasClass('not-submittable')) { return true; }`

Answer (score 4):

> Quote OP:  "I have a form that I don't want to be submitted the first
>   time submit is clicked, but the second time it should work like a
>   normal submit."

Use jQuery `.one()` to block the `submit` on first click only.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').one('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do what you need to do on first click
}
```

Alternatively...

```
$('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').one('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do what you need to do on first click
    if ( some-condition ) {  // under certain conditions allow submit on first click
        $(this).submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Shortest code. Maybe you could add that he can use `$(this).removeAttr()` (as an example) inside the function.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, thank-you.  I'll leave it up to the reader to insert whatever they want on my commented line.  Apparently the OP can't use this solution anyway.

Comment: True that. I only mentioned it to make it clear to the OP that he don't have to re-query all the time and how he can access the element itself.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, still not understanding why he can't make this simple solution work.

Comment: It's because the `.one()` method will only run on the FIRST click, and the user might not have satisfied the conditions for submission until the Nth click.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel, See the very first sentence in the OP: _"I have a form that I don't want to be submitted the first time submit is clicked, but the second time it should work like a normal submit."_

Comment: @Sparky - I completely agree with you, but he changed the requirements in his comment: *The form cannot be submitted until certain conditions are met. These conditions could be met on the first or 20th submit.*

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel, I'm only answering the question as presented.  If the OP wants to contradict his own question within the comments, then good luck to him.

Comment: I completely agree - for the sake of other users who may view this question, I edited the OP and added a strikethrough to the original first line, so that people can see what was originally asked.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel, IMO, I think edits that change the entire meaning of the question should be left up to the OP.  It's a bad enough practice when the OP turns a question into a chameleon, I don't think it should be encouraged for others to it to another's OP.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `.click()`, try using the `.on()` and `.off()` methods to bind and unbind the event. In your case:

```
$('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE.not-submittable').on("click.stopSubmit", function(event) {

    $('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').removeClass('not-submittable');
    $('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').val('Continue');
    $('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').removeAttr('disabled');

    if (...conditions are met.....) {
        $('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE.not-submittable').off("click.stopSubmit");
    }

    return false;
});
```

You may notice that the first parameter of the `.on()` method is the string representation of the handler, but that I appended the namespace ".stopSubmit". Namespacing your handlers allows you to unbind one specific click handler, rather than all click handlers. The best part about this is that if there is code in your original handler that you still want to use you can make a separate click handler to run that code, and it will not be unbound when you unbind the ".stopSubmit" handler.

Please note that `.on()` and `.off()` are the recommended bind/unbind methods - jQuery no longer recommends `.bind()` and `.unbind()`.

**UPDATE**
After reading your comment about not unbinding until after certain conditions are met, I would would like to point out that you can insert the `.off()` call in a conditional. I have updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: If he could use `.on()` and `.off()`, then why can't he use `.one()` instead?

Comment: I was suggestign `.on()` and `.off()` in case there was other code in the method that he wants to still run after he stops the code that prevents the submit. Essentially, `.on()` and `.off()` will make it more extensible. The `.one()` method is a valid solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

If there are certain criteria that must match use this where `submitable` contains your logic what makes it possible to send the form:

```
var submit = $('form#survey_7042 #ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE');
submit.addClass('not-submittable');

submit.click(function(event) {
    if (true == submitable) {
        submit.removeClass('not-submittable').val('Continue').removeAttr('disabled');
        submit.unbind();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```